# An alternative to pythons "setdefault" augmented assignment

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict, setdefault

I want a dictionary that shows boolean counts. I.e. how often name/position combination meets criteria. E.g.:

```
Key - Value1 - Value2
John12 Yes:300 No:25 
John13 Yes:400 No:29 
Linda13 Yes:300 No:60
```

...

I tried this:

```
if str(f[1]) + str(f[7]) in psHpGrp:
    if f[6] == 1:
        psHpGrp.setdefault(str(f[1]) + str(f[7]), []) +=1
```

And because of a bug I got "SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment"

So googling gave me this:

```
if str(f[1]) + str(f[7]) in psHpGrp:
    if f[6] == 1:
        i = psHpGrp.setdefault((f[1]) + str(f[7]), [])
        i += 1    
    else:
        j = psHpGrp.setdefault((f[1]) + str(f[7]), [])
        j += 1 
else:
    psHpGrp.setdefault(str(f[1]) + str(f[7]), []).append(str(f[1]) + str(f[7]))
```

And now I get: j += 1 'int' object is not iterable

Whats wrong here?

Comment: You're trying to add an `int` to a `list`. Could you be a bit clearer on what kind of structure you want to build?

Comment: Your then-branch looks exactly like the else-branch.  Doesn't that make you at least a little nervous? ;-)

Comment: Yes, any recomendations?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['a'] += 1
>>> d['b'] += 1
>>> d['b'] += 1
>>> print d['a'], d['b'], d['c']
1 2 0
```

Comment: Just to make it clear: `defaultdict` is instantiated with a certain class (in this case, `int`). If you retrieve a key that is not in the dictionary, it's first initialized to `defaultclass()` and then returned (ie. there's never a `KeyError` for this dict). `int()` is `0`, as you may test :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

psHpGrp.setdefault(str(f[1]) + str(f[7]), Counter()).update([f[6] == 1])
```

The first part:

```
psHpGrp.setdefault(str(f[1]) + str(f[7]), Counter())
```

will take the object for the key `str(f[1]) + str(f[7])` from the dictionary `psHpGrp` and if it is not present, create a new `Counter`.

Then it will `.update([f[6] == 1])` it with the result of the condition `f[6] == 1`, which can be `True` or `False`. The `Counter` holds then the number of `True`s and `False`s as a dictionary. They represent your `"Yes"/"No"`, just they are booleans.

Answer (score 0):

like @larsmans said, you can't add an int to a list (using `+=`). On your initial attempt replace `[]` with `0`, and then increment the number for that entry.

```
if str(f[1]) + str(f[7]) in psHpGrp:
    if f[6] == 1:
        psHpKey = str(f[1]) + str(f[7])
        psHpGrp.setdefault(psHpKey, 0)
        psHpGrp.setdefault[psHpKey] +=1
```

**Also:** Your final error seems to be arising from code that you have not posted. Python lets you know on which line the offending code is, it's best to post **at least** that line of code.